# Error in connecting PersistenceManagerFactoryand Persistence.xml

Tags: java, h2, jdo, datanucleus

My goal is to do CRUD operation using datanucleus, h2 database in java. but getting stuck in connecting PersistenceManagerFactory and persistence.xml

I have tried with different versions of datanucleus-core,h2database,datanucleus-api-jdo. I am currently referring to the official document: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/getting_started.html

Main code file

```
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Tutorial");
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

        pm.currentTransaction().begin();
        try {
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(1);
            user.setUser("himmat");
            user.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
            user.setMobileNo("7896585687");
            pm.currentTransaction().commit();
        }finally {
            if(pm.currentTransaction().isActive())
            {
                pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <!-- JDO tutorial "unit" -->
    <persistence-unit name="Tutorial">
        <class>Users</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:mem:nucleus1"/>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

error code

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\shyam\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56680:C:\Users\shyam\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\shyam\eclipse-workspace\DemoJDO\target\classes;C:\Users\shyam\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-api-jdo\5.2.1\datanucleus-api-jdo-5.2.1.jar;C:\Users\shyam\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-core\5.2.1\datanucleus-core-5.2.1.jar;C:\Users\shyam\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-rdbms\5.2.1\datanucleus-rdbms-5.2.1.jar;C:\Users\shyam\.m2\repository\javax\jdo\jdo-api\3.0.1\jdo-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\shyam\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar" Main
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:861)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
javax.jdo.JDOException: Errors were encountered when loading the MetaData for the persistence-unit "Tutorial". See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseMetaData(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:807)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:600)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:316)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
Errors were encountered when loading the MetaData for the persistence-unit "Tutorial". See the nested exceptions for details
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the MetaData for the persistence-unit "Tutorial". See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseMetaData(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:797)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:600)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:316)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jdo/AttributeConverter$UseDefault
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:955)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:251)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:190)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2818)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1095)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jdo.AttributeConverter$UseDefault
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jdo/AttributeConverter$UseDefault
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JDOAnnotationReader.java:955)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:251)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:190)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2818)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1095)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseMetaData(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:797)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:600)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:316)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jdo.AttributeConverter$UseDefault
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: according to "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jdo/AttributeConverter$UseDefault", seems you are missing JDO-API JAR in the classpath! https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jdo/jdo-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties instead of persistence.xml
Actually, I have done a similar example using properties. Another issue is maybe you are missing some dependencies, I am sharing pom.xml. try using that you maybe get the results. It is easy to do if you are using Maven. You also need to do enhance for that as displaying in official docs.

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/getting_started.html

For that, you need to follow

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/enhancer.html

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.automated</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoJDO</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-m3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0-m3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Code of the main file

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass",
                "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","org.h2.Driver");
        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:h2:~/test");
        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","sa");
        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","");
        properties.setProperty("datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll","true");

        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties);
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

 pm.currentTransaction().begin();
try {
//...
//You can use your logic here
//...
            pm.currentTransaction().commit();
        }finally {
            if(pm.currentTransaction().isActive())
            {
                pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }

}
```